# Rundeck sudo-prompt-pattern

Tags: rundeck

I configured project with privateKey authentication. I have server and one node, where i can run all operations, which doesn't require sudo. On the node i have user **test**, who can run commands with sudo. I'm using this user for running jobs from server on node.  When i run the job i get response from node, that i need to type password for user test. There is configuration in rundeck, which allows automate this process. Here is how my project.properties file looks:

```
#Project Test configuration, generated
#Tue Dec 08 10:52:45 UTC 2015
project.name=Test
resources.source.1.config.requireFileExists=false
project.ssh-authentication=privateKey
resources.source.1.config.includeServerNode=true
resources.source.1.config.generateFileAutomatically=true
resources.source.1.config.format=resourcexml
resources.source.1.config.file=/home/vagrant/projects/Test/etc/resources.xml
project.ssh-keypath=/opt/test/keys/test_prv_key
project.description=Test project
resources.source.1.type=file
sudo-command-enabled=true
sudo-password-storage-path=/home/vagrant/var/storage/content/keys/test.password
sudo-prompt-pattern='^\[sudo\] password for .+:.*'
```

The problem is, that rundeck doesn't match the pattern for sudo command and connection is dropped in 3s after asking the password.

Upd.
Did not find solution, therefore give user access to sudo without password (NOPASSWD in sudoers)

Comment: how this question relates to regular expressions?

Comment: http://rundeck.org/docs/plugins-user-guide/ssh-plugins.html#sudo-password-as-a-job-option is much simpler than "sudo-password-storage".. try it out

Comment: There was no problem with sudo-password-storage, but with reaction on password prompt

Comment: Please Help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45961196/rundeck-secondary-sudo-password-authentication-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar problem and after trying every combination of configuration options specified in the documentation I gave up and used this hack instead:

```
echo @option.sudoPassword@ | sudo -S my_command
```

Comment: ehh, same project, same problems :)

Comment: Haha, unfortunately :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply the below config in "/etc/rundeck/project.properties"

```
    project.sudo-command-enabled=true
    project.sudo-command-pattern=^sudo$
```