# rundeck: secondary sudo password authentication not working

Tags: linux, automation, scheduled-tasks, sudo, rundeck

```
  <node 
    name="***"
    tags="***" 
    osFamily="***" 
    username="***"
    hostname="192.168.***.***"
    ssh-authentication="password"
    ssh-password-storage-path="keys/nodes/${node.name}/ssh.password"
    sudo-command-enabled="true"
    sudo-password-storage-path="keys/nodes/${node.name}/sudo.password"
  />
```

Command:

```
sudo mv /temp/hello.txt /path/to/destination/
```

Then I have added the password through key storage.

- I am sure that the password written in sudo.password is correct.
- I have rebooted rundeck server I can't get this working...
- I tried setting sudo-fail-on-prompt-timeout="false"

Error received:

```
Remote command failed with exit status -1 
14:48:18   Sudo execution password response failed: Failed waiting for input prompt: Expected input was not seen in 5000 milliseconds 
14:48:18   Failed: NonZeroResultCode: Remote command failed with exit status -1 

14:48:13   Password:
```

What is it not working???

Answer (score 0):

After hours, I've found the solution...
Control the **sudo-prompt-pattern** attribute! Depending on which OS, distrib, .. you're using, you DO need to modify default value which is ^[sudo] password for .+: .*
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rundeck-discuss/yiYDlfCkJvY